# CP Gear Icon missing? Created new Super Admin account

Tags: users

Having a bit of an issue with user accounts. I created a new user account group (Super Admin) and assigned my user account to this group. Now that I've done that, I can no longer access the main settings area to edit file permissions, fields, sections, etc.

How can I reset my user account so I can access the settings? More importantly, how will I be able to add additional users with the same admin level as my user account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Admin' permission is set on the user level, whereas 'userGroup' permissions are set on the userGroup level. And as far as I know, 'admin' permission should trump any userGroup permissions. I'm not sure how you got locked out, unless you unchecked the 'Admin' checkbox on your user profile settings perhaps? Regardless, setting the 'admin' value to 1 in the `craft_users` table should be sufficient to restore privileges, without clearing out the other tables.

The only way to create other Admins is to check the 'Admin' checkbox on the user profile permissions tab. The next best thing is create a userGroup (called 'administrator' for example) with all of the permission boxes checked. Keep in mind however, that userGroup permissions need to be set explicitly, so if you create a new section, you may need to update the userGroup permissions to allow the new section.

Comment: Interesting. I had created two user groups, Super Admin and then another one called Admin. I wonder if Craft had just gotten confused with the two user groups.

Thanks for the background info!

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution: I ended up clearing out all data in the `craft_usergroups`, `craft_usergroups_users`, `craft_userpermissions`, `craft_userpermissions_usergroups`, `craft_userpermissions_users` tables, then in `craft_users`, I reset the "Admin" field to "1" from "0" and this has solved my problem.